# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 from Codeigniter response

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```
<option value="Petrol/Diesel">Petrol</option><option
value="Petrol/Diesel">Diesel</option>
```

is the output generated when I see it in chrome>network.

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Or I get above error. The code work fine and till the success inside the `<script>`, what am I doing wrong from here?

```
$.each(JSON.parse(result), function() {            
  $('#fuel').append(result);
});
```

Model:

```
public function getFuel($modelid, $variant)
{
  $query= "SELECT * FROM `pms_details` WHERE `model_id` = '".$modelid."' AND `Variant` LIKE '".$variant."' ORDER BY `pms_id` ASC";
  $result = $this->db->query($query);
  return $result->result();

  print_r($result->result());
}
```

View:

```
<select id="fuel" onchange="getKm()" >
  <option value="na">Fuel</option>
</select>

<script>
  function getFuel() {  
    var getVariant = $('#variant').val();
    var car_model = $('#car_model').val();
    console.log("this is inside get Fuel");

    console.log(car_model);
    console.log(getVariant);

    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>pms1/getFuel/"+car_model+"/"+getVariant, 
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(result) {
        $('#fuel').html('<option>SELECT</option>');
        $.each(JSON.parse(result), function() {            
          $('#fuel').append(result);
        });  
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public function getFuel($modelid, $variant) 
{
    $car_model = $modelid;
    $getVariant = $variant;

    $this->load->model('M_address');
    $fuel = $this->M_address->getFuel($modelid,$variant);

    $fuel_list = array();
    foreach ($fuel as $fuels) 
    {
      array_push($fuel_list, $fuels->fuel);
    }
    $fuel_list = array_unique($fuel_list);
    // echo '<option value="na">Fuel</option>';
    foreach ($fuel_list as $fuel) 
    {   
      $ts = explode('/', $fuel);
      $ss = count($ts);
      foreach($ts as $tt)
      {
        echo '<option value="' . $fuel . '">' . $tt . '</option>';
        //I've tries adding json_encode on the above line.
      }
    }                      
  }
```

Comment: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in... OR I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 .
The code work fine till the success inside the script tag,
what am I doing wrong after $.each()

Comment: `result` is a string containing HTML. This is why you cannot parse it to JSON...

Comment: to remove this error - uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in <option value="Petrol/Diesel">Petrol</option><option value="Petrol/Diesel">Diesel</option>- what should be done then?

Comment: Well why are you even doing that? The response is a HTML string. There's no need to call `$.each` on it in the first place to generate that error

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Without $.each line I'm not getting my output. So I prefer using json only. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, so return JSON if you want a JSON response... right now youre returning a HTML string

Comment: yup,     $options = array();
            foreach ($fuel_list as $fuel) 
            {   
              $ts = explode('/', $fuel);
              $ss = count($ts);
              foreach($ts as $tt)
              {
                $options[] = array('value' => $fuel, 'name' => $tt);
                              }
            }
            echo json_encode($options); 

as answered by another user below...

can you tell me how can I have unique value for $option? 
array_unique($options) or json_encode($options); doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use json then you need to do something like the following:

Controller:

```
$options = array();
foreach ($fuel_list as $fuel) 
{   
  $ts = explode('/', $fuel);
  $ss = count($ts);
  foreach($ts as $tt)
  {
    $options[] = array('value' => $fuel, 'name' => $tt);
    //echo '<option value="' . $fuel . '">' . $tt . '</option>';
    //I've tries adding json_encode on the above line.
  }
}
echo json_encode($options);
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>pms1/getFuel/"+car_model+"/"+getVariant, 
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    $('#fuel').html('<option>SELECT</option>');
    $.each(result, function (index, data) {
         var new_option = new Option(data.name, data.value);
         $('#fuel').append(new_option);
    });
  }
});
```

Although you could also probably just forgo $.each and append the result like so (using your method):

```
success: function(result) {
        $('#fuel').html('<option>SELECT</option>');
        //$.each(JSON.parse(result), function() {            
          $('#fuel').append(result);
        //});  
      }
```

Comment: your solution works fine.
Thanks.
Unfortunately removing $.each line isn't giving me output.

just one more, how can I do this 
     echo json_encode(array_unique($options));      ??
error: <p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Array to string conversion</p>

Thanks again for your help

Comment: You don't have to do that there it was done before in your code... And array unique won't work for multidimensional array.

Comment: vote-cast for those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but not shown publicly. I get this message. maybe your vote-count has already been increased :)

Comment: strange, usually you only see  that when upvoting on someone elses question when you aren't above a certian rep.

Comment: IDK, it says the same message , I sincerely wants to up vote for your effort, I'm sorry I don't have option for that as of yet.